# Sql query to select previous rows based some sequenceIDs

Tags: sql, postgresql, psql

I have some table, something like below  based on the sequence number column I need to select other devices and value

```
SequenceNumber |  userID | deviceId | Value 
   45          | u123    | did1     | 45      
   44          | u123    | did1     | 50   
   43          | u123    | did2     | 102   
   42          | u123    | did1     | 20   
   41          | u123    | did1     | 30   
   40          | u123    | did2     | 40   
   39          | u123    | did3     | 50
   38          | u123    | did2     | 60   
   37          | u123    | did4     | 60   
   36          | u123    | did1     | 70
```

From the above table, I need to get the below result, in this sample whenever the value clm is more  than 100, its sequence number is 43  so now I need to get the last value of other deviceIds where their sequence number is less than this 43.

The resultant table should look like

```
 SequenceNumber |  userID | deviceId | Value 
   42          | u123    | did1     | 20    
   39          | u123    | did3     | 50   
   37          | u123    | did4     | 60
```

I start with a simple query something like below

```
select SequenceNumber, deviceId from sensors.devices where value > 100 order by SequenceNumber asc limit 1
```

if there are multiple rows where the value is > 100, will order by seqeucneNumber and select the lowest

I need some suggestions for selecting the last value of all other deviceIds where their sequence number is below 43

Comment: What if you have multiple rows where value  is > 100?

Comment: I need to  order by seqeucneNumber and select the lowest

Answer (score 0):

```
with temp as
(
    select s.SequenceNumber,s.deviceId from devices s 
    where s.value > 100 
    order by s.SequenceNumber asc limit 1  
),
temp2 as
(  
    select d.*, RANK()  OVER ( 
            PARTITION by d.deviceid
            ORDER BY d.sequencenumber DESC
        ) rank1 from  devices d , temp t 
    where 
    t.sequencenumber>d.sequencenumber and 
    t.deviceid<>d.deviceid
)
 
select d2.* from temp2 t3 
inner join devices d2 on (t3.sequencenumber=d2.sequencenumber)
where  t3.rank1=1
```

[image]